# Setting Up a mobile specific site url

Tags: iis, iis-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IIS 7.5 Redirect / URL Rewrite to mobile version of website](https://serverfault.com/questions/238706/iis-7-5-redirect-url-rewrite-to-mobile-version-of-website)

I have a website setup at https://www.example.com, hosted on IIS 7.5.

I would like to add a mobile version of my application at https://m.example.com.

How do I create a seperate site that can be accessed via https://m.example.com?

Comment: I'm not trying to redirect someone. Rather, I'm trying to figure out how to setup the "m." portion. How do I add m. to my url?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an entry to your DNS host, most of the time, your domain registrar can handle that.

If you're going to use a virtual host on IIS (I don't know how it works on IIS), you must set up a virtual host to listen on m.example.com and add an A/AAAA (IPV4/IPV6) entry to your DNS, like :

```
1.2.3.4 m.example.com
```

So that when someone connect on m.example.com, it's redirected to the (same) server, and IIS does the switch with a virtual host listening for incoming HTTP connections with the 'Host: m.example.com' header.

I don't know if I am clear, but well, I tried !